# Create text string based upon money value Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can any one Provide me the information on how to create a text String based upon money value.

example:
Negative value: -237.16
Expected output: minus two hundred and thirty seven pounds and sixteen pence

Zero value: 0.00
Expected output: zero pounds and zero pence

Positive value: 237.16
Expected output: two hundred and thirty seven pounds and sixteen pence.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create your database (it can be a List and/or Map), like this:

[image]

(2) Parse your number: it is negative or positive, it is integer or decimal

(3) According to length of whole part and decimal part, combine number words from your database and get your string wished.

There is this package [numbers_to_words](https://pub.dev/packages/number_to_words)